# Differential operator is surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, operator-theory

Let $V = \mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ be the vector space of all polynomials with degree $\leq n$ and coefficients $c_k$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Let the operator $D$ be defined as
$$D\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k x^k\right):=\sum_{k=1}^{n} kc_k x^{k-1}.$$

I need to prove/disprove injectivity and surjectivity. Injectivity is pretty easy to disprove, but for surjectivity is D mapping to $\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$? Hence  $D:\mathbb{R}_{n}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$?. But how can I show that all polynomials in $\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$ have a pre-image from $\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$?

Comment: @lulu: of course, thank you, edited it

Comment: No problem.  For surjectivity, just consider the usual algebraic  integral $x^k\mapsto \frac {x^{k+1}}{k+1}$

Comment: i would suppose the problem is asking you to consider surjectivity back onto the same space all guys of degree at most n

Comment: @lulu: so in order to show that D is surjective it would suffice to show that every polynomial has an anti derivative with the integral operator?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly. $\quad$